# Samsung SCX-4x24-Series-2 driver?

Tags: drivers, printing, samsung

Please tell me where I can get an Ubuntu driver for a Samsung SCX=4x24-Series-2.

Answer (score 2):

The [Samsung Unified Linux Driver](http://www.bchemnet.com/suldr/) might be appropriate. I haven't tested it driver, but this [installation guide](http://ubuntuforums.org/showpost.php?p=2033542&postcount=1) looks up to date.

I hope this helps point you in the right direction.